# How to block multiple instances of TorBrowser? (Prevent accidentally opening another one from a different folder.)

Tags: windows-10, firefox, tor

I have multiple instances of TorBrowser browser set up, in their own folders.

They maintain their own configs, guard node, etc. Sometimes I accidentally open a second instance. It works, but uses the existing `tor.exe`, and you don't have the tor circuit button to the left of the URL.

I want to block multiple instances from opening. With Firefox Portable, you just set `AllowMultipleInstances=false` in `FirefoxPortable.ini`. There are no `.ini` files in the TorBrowser directory structure containing "multiple" and I also checked `about:config` for "multiple."

(TorBrowser is built from Firefox Portable, and it uses Firefox extensions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what I want.  If tor.exe is running, TorBrowser won't start, and the command window stays open with the message. Otherwise TorBrowser starts and the command window closes. This also allows a regular Firefox browser session to be running at the same time.

```
@echo off
tasklist | find /i "tor.exe" > nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
"C:\ [TorBrowser path] \Browser\firefox.exe"
exit    
:running
echo "Another TorBrowser is already running. (tor.exe is running.)"
@pause
```

Comment: Absolutely great self-solved answer!

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention OS, but for Windows, the following batch file makes *Firefox* single instance. Start the browser using a shortcut to the batch file, rather than directly. You might adapt it for *Tor*.

```
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
exit    
:running
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NirSoft\NirCmd\nircmd" win activate process firefox.exe 
exit
```

##### Notes

- Nirsoft's [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is only used to focus a running instance of *Firefox*. Omit if you prefer to raise the window manually.
- Untested for other applications.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me (your tasklist / errorlevel part). In my answer, I just search for tor.exe, and if it's not found I start TorBrowswer. This also avoids a problem if I have a regular firefox browser open. I want to be able to run them at the same time.